# Python Pandas Split Column String Values into Separate Columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame like this:
[image]

With the lineup column in the format 'QB Aaron Rodgers RB Josh Jacobs RB Boston Scott FLEX Antonio Gibson WR Davante Adams WR Adam Thielen WR Allen Lazard TE Mark Andrews DST Patriots'

I need to break up the lineup column into separate columns based on position.
Final DataFrame will look like this:

[image]

I have tried this line of code:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(df.Lineup.str.split(' ').tolist(), columns = ['DST','FLEX','QB','RB1','RB2','TE','WR1','WR2','WR3'])
```

But I am getting an error.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what went wrong with your attempts? Please [edit] to include a [mcve] with your sample input and expected output as text, not as images or links, and _code_ showing your efforts so that we better understand how to help

Comment: @G.Anderson Just did!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realistically, having the `Lineup` column be formatted in such a way that the difference between your keys and the content would be really helpful. Commas in between roles, or something could really help make the parsing easier.

I'm sure there is a more elegant way to solve this type of problem, however, I setup a dictionary keyed with your indicator characters `['DST','FLEX','QB','RB','TE','WR']`. In my code below, I assume that your data is always in groups of `3` and one group of `2` which is the last one. If this is an incorrect assumption you'll need to correct that portion of the program.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Rank": [1],
    "EntryId": ["2210633437"],
    "EntryName": ["180DegreesMiami (2/3)"],
    "TimeRemaining": [0],
    "Points": [214.06],
    "Lineup": ["QB Aaron Rodgers "
               "RB Josh Jacobs "
               "RB Boston Scott "
               "FLEX Antonio Gibson "
               "WR Davante Adams "
               "WR Adam Thielen "
               "WR Allen Lazard "
               "TE Mark Andrews "
               "DST Patriots"],
    "WeekSeason": ["12020"],
    "Player": ["Boston Scott"],
    "Roster Position": ["RB"],
    "FPTS": [7.4]
})


def process_column(s):
    splits = s.split(' ')
    d = {}
    for key, *rest in [splits[i:i + 3] for i in range(0, len(splits), 3)]:
        d.setdefault(key, []).append(' '.join(rest))

    d2 = {}
    for key, values in d.items():
        if len(values) > 1:
            for i, value in enumerate(values):
                d2[f'{key}{i + 1}'] = value
        else:
            d2[key] = values[0]
    return pd.Series(d2)


df = pd.merge(df, df.Lineup.apply(process_column), left_index=True, right_index=True).drop(columns=['Lineup'])
```

The program produced the following output:

| Index | Rank | EntryId | EntryName | TimeRemaining | Points | WeekSeason | Player | Roster Position | FPTS | QB | RB1 | RB2 | FLEX | WR1 | WR2 | WR3 | TE | DST |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2210633437 | 180DegreesMiami (2/3) | 0 | 214.06 | 12020 | Boston Scott | RB | 7.4 | Aaron Rodgers | Josh Jacobs | Boston Scott | Antonio Gibson | Davante Adams | Adam Thielen | Allen Lazard | Mark Andrews | Patriots |

Feel free to rearrange the columns as desired.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the names with `regex` by splitting on the positions. Then create a `dictionary` by zipping the positions and the names. The result can be turned into a dataframe which is then concatenated with the existing dataframe. To use your sample string:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

def get_names(text):
    names = [i.strip() for i in re.split('QB |RB |FLEX |WR |TE |DST ', text) if i]
    positions = ['QB', 'RB1', 'RB2', 'FLEX', 'WR1', 'WR2', 'WR3', 'TE', 'DST']
    return dict(zip(positions, names))

df = pd.DataFrame(['QB Aaron Rodgers RB Josh Jacobs RB Boston Scott FLEX Antonio Gibson WR Davante Adams WR Adam Thielen WR Allen Lazard TE Mark Andrews DST Patriots'], columns=['Lineup'])
d = df['Lineup'].apply(get_names)

df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(d.tolist())], axis = 1)
```

Output:

|  | Lineup | QB | RB1 | RB2 | FLEX | WR1 | WR2 | WR3 | TE | DST |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | QB Aaron Rodgers RB Josh Jacobs RB Boston Scott FLEX Antonio Gibson WR Davante Adams WR Adam Thielen WR Allen Lazard TE Mark Andrews DST Patriots | Aaron Rodgers | Josh Jacobs | Boston Scott | Antonio Gibson | Davante Adams | Adam Thielen | Allen Lazard | Mark Andrews | Patriots |